# dotnet, how to set Environment Variable 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'?

Tags: .net, json, ocr

I want to use OCR using Text Detection in Google Cloud Vision. So, I downloaded Text detection sample source and tested it.

In my local text, text detection works properly.
using local path : 
`my computer-advanced system setting-enviroment variable-add new 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' & json path`

So, I immigrate that code to my server. But, when I run OCR function, error message appeared.

> Error reading credential file from location MY-JSON-FILEPATH . Please check the value of Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Local program can access my local json file, but in my server can't access that file. However, I don't know how to set environment variable in dotnet.

So. I want to need help. Thank you.

My programming language is .net using visual studio 2012 + IIS 6.0

[error message capture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTqVM.png)

Comment: You should put your json file to server, and change your file path to the server relative path, this may help you [MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Alex, thank you for your comment. But, there is no code to set path anywhere...

Comment: By [GoogleCredentials](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/6e0f449fd72685a35b15b474a04d04a07aed9a7a/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Auth.PlatformServices_Shared/OAuth2/GoogleCredential.cs), it have another way to get the credential - FromStream, you can try that

Comment: Thank you very much @Alex !! Your tips, MapPath and Credentials by Stream, make my OCR function work properly.